# How does facebook detects webview or embedded browser

Tags: javascript, flutter, webview, embedded-browser

1. How does facebook detects this type of browsers ?
2. Is there any way to tricked that and make it as a native web browser such as a js code or something elese ?

[image]

> for your account security, logging in to Facebook from an embedded browser is disabled. To continue, download and log in to the Facebook app on your device and try agian.

I am using flutter webview:

```
WebView(
   javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
   initialUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/',
   onPageFinished: controller.webViewOnPageFinished,
)
```

Comment: I'ts a mess. It detects my default navigator on android as a webview also.

Answer (score -2):

Facebook Already deprecated Login on embedded browsers.
You can see more details in the [official documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/).